# 2 markers in my map (openstreetmap)

Tags: android, osmdroid

Well. 
i have an irritating problem and i dont know how to fix it !!

When i get the lat and lng form gps. The map shows 2 markers ( one icon by default and another  icon customized by me).
i need the costumized icon appears on the map!!

pd: i already change the path on the method DRAW()

here is my code.

```
myOpenMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
    myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myMapController = myOpenMapView.getController();
    myMapController.setZoom(12);

    myOpenMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);


    ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray;
    anotherOverlayItemArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(Double.valueOf(lat),
                                     (Double.valueOf(lng)));


    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem("US", "US", geoPoint));
    myMapController.setCenter(geoPoint);
    myMapController.animateTo(geoPoint);


    DefaultResourceProxyImpl defaultResourceProxyImpl = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this);
    MyItemizedIconOverlay myItemizedIconOverlay = new MyItemizedIconOverlay(anotherOverlayItemArray, null, defaultResourceProxyImpl);

    myOpenMapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedIconOverlay);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it deleting the super.draw(...) call on draw overrided function of my own ItemizedIconOverlay class.

Hope it helps!

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** The solution explained above seems to cause problems on marker tap action (we have to call super.draw method).

To fix this I have left behind my CustomItemizedOverlay class and changed the icon using setMarker(Drawable d) method of OverlayItem on each element instead, rude but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable newMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);    

mMyLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(anotherOverlayItemArray,
            newMarker, "listener", new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getActivity()));

    mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
```

or maybe the `myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation(); is enabled` this means it will show the default marker for location on the map